# Happy holidays, Philosophy!

Tags: discussion, community

**Happy holidays, everyone!**

Well, it's been a long and wonderful year! I just wanted to say that I'm really thankful for the community here, and that I continue to be excited to be part of it as it experiences its remarkable and exciting journey. I can't wait for next year, and hopefully many more years to come.

In light of the generosity of the season, I thought it might be a good time to mention that we've had an awful lot of new users joining the community over the last weeks and months. In order to maintain the robustly open and welcoming environment we have long enjoyed, it's incumbent upon all of us to continue to be as charitable and kind as we can.

Enjoy the holidays, Philosophy! May they be warm and cozy.

Comment: Does this question apply to summer holidays as well?